# Firebase Cloud Messaging not sending data payload

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

From the Firebase Cloud Messaging documentation at [Defining message payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#defining_the_message_payload):

> You can specify one or both message types by creating an object with
>   the ***data*** and / or ***notification*** keys.

The documentation gives the example of a Combined Message:

```
var payload = {
  notification: {
    title: "$GOOG up 1.43% on the day",
    body: "$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day."
  },
  data: {
    stock: "GOOG",
    open: 829.62,
    close: "635.67"
  }
};
```

Also from the documentation at [Handle notification messages in a backgrounded app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#backgrounded):

> This includes messages that contain both notification and data payload
>   (and all messages sent from the Notifications console). In these
>   cases, the notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and
>   the data payload is delivered in the ***extras of the intent*** of your
>   launcher Activity.

I'm sending a notification with this payload:

```
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: '...',
        body: '...',
    },
    data: {
        test: "test"
    },
};
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(...)
```

But `extras` is always null:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App behavior when receiving messages that include both **notification and data payloads** depends on whether the app is in the background or the foreground—essentially, whether or not it is active at the time of receipt.

- When in the background, apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification.
- When in the foreground, your app receives a message object with both payloads available.

*So, basically if the app is in foreground the intent wouldn't have any notification extras. if that's not the case your doing something wrong in configuration.*

Comment: I´ll have to take a second look at this. My app is running in the background, but when I tap the notification I'm not receiving the data payload.

Comment: Or I could just use the data message and handle the notifications myself

Comment: I'm sorry. I have to unmark your answer. There is a bug in Firebase and it is not behaving according to the documentation.

Comment: There was no bug after all. It was a stupid mistake from my part.

Comment: @rubenlop can you explain what stupid mistake you doing. cause i have a same problem here now.. and i m not able to solve..

Comment: @SagarChavada I turns out there was a "SplashScreenActivity" that was receiving the Intent with the data payload, and then this Activity was launching my MainActivity, without any payload.

Comment: Superb... thats right..  same case here cause first splash screen is appearing and i m checking in MainActivity... thank you for the quick response,

Comment: I don't have a splash screen and yet this problem does exist. The intent data is null. I am trying to send a notification. with payload using the Firebase console.